# Right Aligning Text with CSS

Tags: css

HTML

```
<body>
        <div class="menu_items">
            <h1>My Heading</h1>
            <nav>
                <a>Item 1</a>
                <a>Item 2</a>
                <a>Item 3</a>
                <a>Item 4</a>
            </nav>
        <div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.menu_items nav a
{
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

This does not appear to move the `menu_items` to the right side of the page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to move the `text-align` to `.menu_items nav`

```
.menu_items nav {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put text-align: right on the parent container - in this case the nav tag, not on the individual  tags if you want them to align to the right.

```
nav {
    text-align: right;
}
```